# Why are links inside an iFrame opening in system safari?

Tags: cordova, iframe, cordova-ios

Between builds (I am unsure what changed to trigger this), an application went from the following behavior in iOS.

- A main webview loads `index.html`, and has an iframe that has many anchors in it
- Anchors would stay inside the iFrame unless otherwise manipulated and redirected with JavaScript that runs from `index.html`

To:

- A main webview loads `index.html`, and has an iframe that has many anchors in it
- Clicking any anchor inside of the iFrame *or* any action that triggers a location change results in the new page being loaded in the Safari App rather than inside the iFrame

I have the latest version of `cordova-plugin-inappbrowser` (1.3.0 at this time) installed, but that does not seem to be interfering with anything.

I have verified that I am still able to use JavaScript from `index.html` to change attributes about anchors inside the frame, as well as to add events.

I am using the following CSP:

`<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"
        content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval';">`

I am unsure if that has something to do with it.

I've tried a number of iframe sandbox properties in an attempt to see what sticks, and none of them change outcome. Currently it's at:

`<iframe id="the-iframe" sandbox="allow-scripts allow-modals allow-popups allow-popups-to-escape-sandbox allow-top-navigation allow-forms allow-same-origin"></iframe>`

The `src` of the iframe is set dynamically.

I have opened up a [bug report](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-11087) on cordova to see if this is potentially a bug rather than a feature.

Comment: How are you using the `cordova-plugin-inappbrowser` in your application? Are you perhaps forcing all links to be opened using `inappbrowser` as described [here](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser#installation)?

Comment: I was originally using inappbrowser to capture certain link clicks and manually opening them in `_system` target, but have removed the code and the plugin and the issue persists.

Comment: So I just rebuilt this with cordova-ios 3.8.0 and it works without an issue, but building it with cordova-ios 4.1.1 causes this issue. Looks like I've at least isolated how to figure out the change.

Answer (score 3):

I was facing this issue for a new application I'm working now, and it seems that is related with new whitelisting mode in Cordova iOS > 6. For us, I have made a workaround for allow navigation inside iframes (I can't be sure if it could generate any other problem, but for now we haven't seem anyone).
In cordova project, at `Private/Plugins/CDVUIWebViewEngine/CDVIntentAndNavigationFilter.m`, we've just modified the `shouldOverrideLoadWithRequest:navigationType:` method, changing the behaviour when a navigation is requested via `UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked`.

With the new Cordova behaviour, in that case it stops navigation, and open it in system browser; I've commented that line (`[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];` ) and modified the return, to `return YES`; and with this two changes it is working as previous versions of cordova:

```
case UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked:
    // Note that the rejection strings will *only* print if
    // it's a link click (and url is not whitelisted by <allow-*>)
    if ([self.allowIntentsWhitelist URLIsAllowed:url logFailure:NO]) {
        // the url *is* in a <allow-intent> tag, push to the system
        //[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
        return YES;
    } else {
        [errorLogs addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:allowIntents_whitelistRejectionFormatString, [url absoluteString]]];
    }
```

I think that this behaviour should be configurable from config.xml parameter, but for us this workaround is enough right now.